# Proper use of maiden name

Tags: names

I want to include my mother's maiden name on her gravestone. What is the proper form? ( I don't care for the use of *nee*.)

Which of the following is appropriate?

1. First Name, Maiden name, Married name
2. First name, (Maiden Name), Married name
3. First Name, Married Name, (Maiden name)

Comment: It’s whatever pleases you the most.  Take a vote among her close survivors.

Comment: The English part of this question has to do with the (  ).  Forget the (  )!  (And, of course, no commas.) The usual form would be First Name Maiden Name Married Name.  For example, Elizabeth Brewster Smith.  But the real guideline, is, what would your mother want?

Comment: But in the UK, the maiden name isn't generally adopted as a surname like it appears to be in the US (Elizabeth Brewster Smith; Hillary Rodham Clinton...). So the answer is culture-dependent. In the UK, the usual form would be "Elizabeth Smith (née Brewster)" but I don't think I recall ever seeing maiden names mentioned on gravestones at all. I'm not convinced this is a question about the English language.

Comment: I would suggest you ask the undertaker or gravestone folks what practice is most accepted.

Comment: @Andrew: the traditional usage in the U.S. is that the maiden name is used as a middle name, not as a surname. In previous centuries, some people gave only their sons and not their daughters middle names to leave room for the maiden name to be a middle name after they got married.

Comment: @PeterShor - Middle names have been routinely given to women in the US for at least a century.

Comment: @Hot Licks: I said "some people", not "all people." I suspect that in the U.S., in the late 19th and early 20th centuries, a considerably higher percentage of men than women had middle names.

Comment: what's wrong with _née_? Throw a little French in there; a Romance language is an apt tongue to use on a gravestone. I'd be inclined to think option 2 though.

Comment: I suspect that "First Name Maiden name Married name" (no commas) is by far the most common in the U.S. But there aren't any regulations about this, so you can do whatever you think is best.

Comment: @PeterShor - Don't have any records at hand to check other members of my family, but both my mother and my aunt on my father's side had "middle" names.  Both born over 100 years ago.  (But just now checking records online I see that my grandmother on my father's side had a middle name as well.)

Comment: @Hot Licks: there are at least two cases in my and my wife's family tree where the daughters had no middle names, although their brothers did. I believe (although memory can be unreliable) that my mother told me that this was to "leave room" for their maiden names to be their middle names when they got married. But some, if not all, of the women on my father's side were given middle names.